# como tornar este código de banner 728x90 pixels responsivo?

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Este é o código é do banner de um programa de afiliados, tamanho 728x90 pixels. Coloquei ele no blog mas em dispositivos móveis o banner esta ficando cortado, poderiam ajudar?

```
<!-- Começo -->
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    lmd_source="35882772";
    lmd_si="33921764";
    lmd_pu="22765282";
    lmd_c="BR";
    lmd_wi="728";
    lmd_he="90";
</script>
<script src="http://image.lomadee.com/js/ad_lomadee.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
<!-- fim -->
```

Comment: Melhore a pergunta não tem como te ajudar só com isso!

Answer (score 2):

Infelizmente isso não é possível.

Esses anúncios possuem tamanho fixo e criam um frame na página no qual você não conseguirá fazer alterações (não sei o Lomadee, mas o Adsense possui opção de banner para design responsivo). Além do que, provavelmente isso infrige os Termos de Uso do programa. Portanto, não é recomendado alterar características de banners de anúncios, sob pena de ser banido do sistema.

Uma solução que puxa um banner com largura específica para cada tela, é esta proposta [neste artigo](http://www.escolawp.com/2012/09/como-usar-anuncios-do-google-adsense-num-layout-responsivo/) relacionada ao Adsense, mas acredito ser possível adaptá-lo ao Lomadee.

**Como funciona?**

Ao abrir o site, de acordo com o `window.innerWidth`, o script irá carregar o banner que se encaixa à largura da tela.

**Possível problema:** (mas não tão importante)

Caso a página seja aberta em um iPad, por exemplo, na posição "paisagem" (dispositivo na horizontal) e carregue o banner de 728x90 pixels, quando o usuário girar para a posição "retrato" (na vertical), o banner irá ficar cortado, isso porque a largura em pixels na posição "retrato" é menor. No entanto, creio que isso não seja grande problema, pois o usuário em dispositivos móveis tem mais tendência a abrir na posição "paisagem" do que na "retrato". E se ele abrir na posição "retrato" inicialmente, melhor ainda, pois se mudar para "paisagem" o banner não será cortado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Caro amigo,

Troque a seguinte linha

```
lmd_wi="728";
```

por

```
lmd_wi="100%";
```